# Is using object oriented programming better than a simple callback function

Tags: oop

For example, if I want to have a dropDown and a text field on the UI. And Everytime I change the dropdown, the text content will change as well.

I am thinking I could write with a simple callback function using switch-case, but also create a dropDown class, and have a method inside to update the text content, and relate the eventlistener to the @class.method.

So, what's the difference? Do I really need to use object for this simple event? What event might the OOP be preferrable?

I am new to OOP and really confused on when I should use it.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: For what you're trying to do, the callback function is the most natural way to handle it in javascript.  But that's just my opinion.  This really isn't an opinion site, and this question is likely to be flagged.

Comment: OOP, in essence, is a tool for managing complexity. For two controls, it doesn't make much difference. But imagine a large enterprise program with hundreds of screens and dozens of controls per screen. You are going to be lost in your switch cases long before you finish the first screen.

Answer (score 0):

You are comparing apples to oranges. Callbacks and OOP are not mutually exclusive concepts, choosing one doesn't push you to forego the other. In your position, I would go with the simplest solution. Actually, I would always go with the simplest solution.

OOP can be confusing and its usefulness is in debate. Some people think it can lead to deep structural problems and some others think that it is the only way to develop software. I myself am in the former camp.

Try not to get too hung up on paradigms. Use whatever is necessary.

Comment: "OOP can be confusing and its usefulness is in debate." - you can't be serious, it has been around for 15 years and it a industry-wide standard.

Comment: Take a look around please, its usefulness really is in debate. And your reasoning doesn't really make a lot of sense. Sexism has been around for longer than 15 years and is an industry-wide standard for many industries, yet one would need to be mentally challenged to tout its values.